# How to properly add ConsoleKeyInfo to return a value right away

Tags: visual-studio-2017, console-application

I figured it out. I Googled this issue to death and found out there was this to use:

option = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar);

I have been Googling and troubleshooting for days. I would like to make this calculator program to return a value as soon as the operator selects a function (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). It looks like from reading and other examples this `ConsoleKeyInfo` should work:
        ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
        string operation = info.Key.ToString();
    When I add it, I cannot get the program to run correctly. I get this:

```
    system.formatexception string must exactly be one character long 
My current code works, but once you select a function (+), you then have to press enter to get the answer.
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp5
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                int Num1, Num2, result;
                char option;
                Console.Write("Enter the First Number : ");
                Num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the Second Number : ");
                Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Select: +, -, *, /");


                option = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (option)
                {
                    case '+':
                        result = Num1 + Num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("The result of Addition is : {0}", result);
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        result = Num1 - Num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("The result of Subtraction is : {0}", result);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        result = Num1 * Num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("The result of Multiplication is : {0}", result);
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        result = Num1 / Num2;
                        Console.WriteLine("The result of Division is : {0}", result);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                        break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

**

Comment: do u press enter after typing the operation? it works fine check https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1tWgf

Comment: option = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()); is ok to use why do u want to change it to Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar?

Comment: My first shot at this coding was I had to press enter to return the answer. My goal was, if the operator pressed * for multiplication it returned the answer right away. I ended up redoing a bit of this code. I could not get my division to return decimals. I ended up using double instead of integers.

Comment: then just do option = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;